# feed_dict can not convert int to tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems that the toughest part of tensorflow is matching tensors to their destinations.

I get the runtime error:
TypeError: "Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a int into a Tensor."

I'm trying to solve the XOR problem, this is my main set up.

```
i = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,2])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1])

inp_vec = [[1.,0.],[0.,1.],[1.,1.],[0.,0.]]
solutions = [[1.],[1.],[0.],[0.]]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )

    for i in range(1000):
       sess.run(optim, feed_dict={i:inp_vec, y_:solutions})
```

Here's the whole code if you need to see more or want tell me what I can do better http://pastebin.com/GqrX21vf

inp_vec is [4x2] and solutions is [4x1]. Both should match the placeholders. I've been having problems with matching ever since I started tensorflow so I'm starting to think I fundamentally don't understand the setup. Clarification on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overwriting the reference to your variable `i` with the `i` of the for loop. Change the name to `x_` should fix the problem.

```
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,2])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1])

inp_vec = [[1.,0.],[0.,1.],[1.,1.],[0.,0.]]
solutions = [[1.],[1.],[0.],[0.]]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )

    for i in range(1000):
       sess.run(optim, feed_dict={x_:inp_vec, y_:solutions})
```